# c program to copy media file from one location to another

Tags: c, file, copy

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
main()
{
int inhandle,outhandle,bytes;
char source[128],target[128],buffer[512];
printf("enter source file name\n");
scanf("%s",source);

inhandle=open(source,O_RDONLY|O_BINARY);
if(inhandle==-1)
{
    printf("cannot open source file\n");
    exit(0);
}
printf("enter target file name\n");
scanf("%s",target);
outhandle=open(target,O_CREAT|O_BINARY,O_WRONLY,S_IWRITE);
if(outhandle==-1)
{

    printf("cannot open target file\n");
    close(outhandle);
    exit(0);
}
while(1)
{
    bytes=read(inhandle,buffer,512);
    if(bytes>0)
    {
        write(outhandle,buffer,bytes);
    }
    else
    break;
}
close(inhandle);
close(outhandle);
}
```

program compiles with 0 errors and when i pass the arguments in scanf there even no errors related to opening the file is thrown.i cannot seem to copy any media file like .avi format with this program,the file does gets created in its target location but with 0 bytes.

Comment: Please consider using fgets(3) instead of scanf(3).  There are various issues with scanf(3).  Please see here, http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your second `open(2)` call:

```
outhandle=open(target,O_CREAT|O_BINARY,O_WRONLY,S_IWRITE);
                                      ^        ^
```

Instead of the second comma, you probably meant a `|`. Because of that comma `O_WRONLY` will be the third argument, the `mode` and the file won't have the correct permissions.